# Creating breadcrumbs for table navigation VUEJS

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, breadcrumbs

I'm a Junior Developer and I'm currently having a big issue with breadcrumbs.

For this application, I'm using VueJS and the problem I'm having is the following:

*The user clicks on 'tables' and is sent to the 'tables' page.

-On that 'tables' page, he has a big table in which he's able to click on the various columns to show a new table with data relevant to the column he clicked on.

*For this I'm on **the same component** so I'm not using routers, but using v-show as I don't want the tables to rerender.

My problem is the following, I have to make a breadcrumbs as he navigates to the different tables (ie: table/holdingList/entrepriseList/clientList..). and they have to be clickable so that I'm able to create a function that injects data into the table or to simply 'show' it and close the others.

Can anyone give me a brief out-line of how to do this? Sorry if it seems trivial. I've already spent a couple of days on it and my brain has turned to mush...

Comment: is there just one subtable depending on the main one or is it possible that child tables can be expanded to new ones? Clicking on a column does hide the main table and display the child table full width?

Comment: Hello,  each table has it's own V-show. The default table when you get on the page is  'HoldingTable', and everytime you click on a column, it shuts the previous table down and opens up a new table using the nested data from the previous. (full width)

Answer (score 0):

I will start from the easiest solution to implement:

- Each v-show will depend on a different data object. Then your breadcrumb has an `@click` method that will set every `v-show` data object to false. Give the method a parameter with the name of the data object that you intend to show and display that to true.

The previous answer is enough to get it working. Other ways of achieving the same result in a more maintainable way are:

- Create one data object named as `activeTable` and turn your `v-show` into a `v-if`. When you click on the breadcrumb element you change the `activeTable` data object to an identifier for the table you wish to display. After that your vue-if simply checks if the `activeTable === thisTableId`. Where `thisTableId` is the identifier of each table.
- You may want to start getting acquainted with Vuex specially if your tables share a similar layout. In that way you will **store** the data and there is no need to request your data again. This is useful if the data to populate your tables come from an API.
- Finally on an **SPA** architecture there is no actual re-render so you may possibly want to look at that as well.

Please read the guidelines for posting an answer since they require you to show at least some effort from your side. Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you for your help! It gave me a couple of great ideas to work with! I'll work on a Store and get the more maintainable solution figured out. Thank you again.